# if statement in python executes a wrong condition

Tags: python-3.x

```
enter=input("Enter a char : ")
if enter=='a' or 'A':
    print("a")
elif enter=='b' or 'B':
    print("b")
else:
    print('c')
```

if I enter any character other than a,A,b,B should print c.But it is printing a, any reason why?
I am new to programming so apologises if it is a silly question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The condition doesn't do what you think. It should be:

```
if enter == 'a' or enter == 'A':
```

Or you can use the `in` operator and a list:

```
if enter in ['a','A']:
```

Do something similar to the other case.